# Post cache substitution is not compatible with modules in the IIS integrated pipeline that modify the response buffers

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I got this error on one of my SharePoint sites.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change this setting in my web.config

```
<urlCompression
 doDynamicCompression="true"
 doStaticCompression="true"
 dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="<this should be false>"/>
```

Set dynamicCompressionBeforeCache to false and it worked for me.

Thanks to this post:
http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/general-discussions-/post-cache-substitution-is-not-compatible-with-modules-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline-that-modify-the-response-buffers

Answer (score 0):

For me, disabling the output cache in the web.config worked, like so:

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
        <outputCache enableOutputCache="false"/>
    </caching>
</system.web>
```